# Best practice to store screen dimension for reuse in Spritekit game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, screen-size

I read out the screen dimensions of the current device in the following way:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
```

I need this value very often in different classes of the game, so I want to avoid calculating these values again and again. What is the best practice to store and reuse these values in the game?

Comment: Anywhere you can access them is fine.

Comment: But how in particular? As a global variable? How do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cand store them in AppDelegate(.h), then call them wherever you need.

```
   @interface AppDelegate :UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    ...
   }
   @property (nonatomic, assign) int MYSCREENHEIGHT;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) int MYSCREENWIDHT;
```

In AppDelegate(.m) you should synthesize them, then:

```
    MYSCREENHEIGHT = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    MYSCREENWIDHT = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
```

In other places just call them:

```
    AppDelegate *appDelGlobal = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    int myScreenHeight = appDelGlobal.MYSCREENHEIGHT;
    int myScreenwidth = appDelGlobal.MYSCREENWIDHT;
```

You can store them in NSUserDefaults also, but this is not the case for you here.